# Is a hashset needed for contains with List(of String) Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, contains, hashset

Would the following:

```
Dim stringlist As List(Of String)
Dim stringlisthas = stringlist.Contains("thing1")
```

be any slower than

```
Dim stringlist As List(Of String)
Dim stringlisthash As New HashSet(Of String)(stringlist)
Dim stringlisthas = stringlisthash.Contains("thing1")
```

Is a hashset needed for contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is a hashset needed for contains?

Needed? No.

> Would [`List<T>.Contains`] be any slower than [`HashSet<T>.Contains`]?

Probably. It depends on how `List<T>.Contains` is implemented (its probably a linear search).

I'll answer a question you didn't ask.

> Does it matter?

It depends. You have to code up both, profile it, and see if it's a bottleneck in your application. If it's not, just stick with `List<T>.Contains`.